# How to access Facebook data in component?

Tags: facebook, ember.js

I am currently developing an Ember.js application which fetches data from Facebook.

The problem I have is that I actually have no idea how to access the data which was fetched in the application route in my component (js/hbs).

I use ember-simple-auth and torii for authentification and data fetching.

My application route currently looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin'

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  fetchCurrentUser() {
    const data = this.get('session.data.authenticated');
    const {accessToken} = data;

    if (accessToken) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        FB.api('/me?fields=name,posts&access_token=' + accessToken, response => {
          resolve()
        })
      })
    }
  },

  beforeModel(transition) {
    this._super(transition);
    if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
      return this.fetchCurrentUser()
    }
  },

  actions: {
    login() {
      return this
        .get('session')
        .authenticate('authenticator:torii', 'facebook-connect')
        .then(() => {
          this.fetchCurrentUser();
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    },

    logout() {
      return this
        .get('session')
        .invalidate()
    }
  }
});
```

I have already searched for an approach but most of the information is outdated.

You can find a twiddle [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/5b7f9da9aa559384880db1df75bfe110)

Does anyone have a suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `model()` hook anywhere in your route? I see the `beforeModel()` hook to handle the transition, but not a model call.  Does that live in your `ApplicationRouteMixin`?

```
model() {
  return this.fetchCurrentUser();
}
```

The model call is typically where your ajax request lives.  The result of `model()` is then passed to `setupController`.  The Controller is what allows your data to be accessed in your template/view.  `setupController` essentially does:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  Ember.set(controller, 'model', model);
}
```

For reference: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/c7db394fe322dcfee0c79a58334103e2dc87a3a1/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1629-L1635

This is called automatically, but without a `model()` call, it does nothing.  Components are stateless--this means they only have access to data we pass to them.  So, if you we have this `model` hook now, then we can pass it to our component in our template:

`{{our-component model=model}}`

`model` returns our data -> `setupController` sets that data on the controller -> `controller` allows us to access that data on our template and pass it to our component.

Let me know if this helps. Feel free to post a twiddle or more info about your mixin if this doesn't help.

Comment: I have added a twiddle as you suggested.